# Formatting of longtblr

Tags: tables, formatting, tabularray

I have the following problem.
In picture 1 (code is attached) I managed to split my table on 2 pages, but the second row is formatted wrong.

This should look like in picture 2, but in picture 2 I can't manage to split the table on 2 pages (there are problems with table and longtblr).

Can anybody help me with that?

Thanks in advance!

[image: How it looks now]
[image: How I would like it]

```
\documentclass[% 
emulatestandardclasses,% sehr ähnlich zu article
fontsize=12pt,
listof=entryprefix,% Verzeichnisabhängiger Präfix für Gleitumgebungsverzeichnisse verwenden
listof=graduated,% trotz Präfix nicht mit automatischer Nummernbreite arbeiten
captions=nooneline,% einzeilige captions nicht zentrieren
captions=heading,% captions als Überschrift formatieren
ngerman,  %english, %wird benötigt, damit englische Literatur im Text englisch zitiert wird
numbers=noenddot,
a4paper, 
DIV12
]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Für das Rotieren des Textes
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{rotating}   % für rotierte Texte
\usepackage{makecell}   % needed
\usepackage{enumitem} % Anpassbare Listen
\usepackage{xcolor}
%\NewTableCommand\TB{\textbullet}
\newcommand\TB{\textbullet}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
    {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
    {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\makeatother


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Tables

\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption}

% German Translation for "Continued on next page" and "Continued from previous page"
\DefTblrTemplate{contfoot-text}{default}{Fortsetzung auf der nächsten Seite}
\DefTblrTemplate{conthead-text}{default}{ - Fortsetzung}
\SetTblrTemplate{contfoot-text}{default}
\SetTblrTemplate{conthead-text}{default}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtblr}[
  label = {tab:conceptmatrix},
  caption = {Challenges - conceptmatrix},
  ]{
    width = \textwidth,
    colspec = {l *{11}{c}}, 
    row{1} = {font=\bfseries, bg=gray!20},
    row{2} = {font=\bfseries, c},
    row{3-Z} = {font=\normalfont},
    cell{2}{2-Z} = {cmd=\rotcell},
    hlines, vlines,
    rowhead = 1,
    rowhead = 2,
  }
  \SetCell[r=2]{c} Challenges 
  &   \SetCell[c=11]{c}   articles
      &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &    \\
      & article1
      & article2
          & article3
                  & article4
                      & article5
                          & article6
                              & article7
                                 & article8
                                      & article9
                                          & article10
                                             & article11 \\
  Challenge 
  & \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
  Challenge 
  & \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
  Challenge 
  & \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
Challenge 
  & \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
  Challenge 
  & \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
  Challenge 
  & \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
Challenge 
  & \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
  Challenge 
  & \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
  Challenge 
  & \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
Challenge 
  & \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
  Challenge 
  & \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
  Challenge 
  & \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
Challenge 
  & \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
  Challenge 
  & \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
  Challenge 
  & \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
Challenge 
  & \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
  Challenge 
  & \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
  Challenge 
  & \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
  Challenge 
  & \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
  Challenge 
  & \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
  Challenge 
  & \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
Challenge 
  & \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
  Challenge 
  & \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
  Challenge 
  & \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
Challenge 
  & \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
  Challenge 
  & \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
  Challenge 
  & \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
Challenge 
  & \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
  Challenge 
  & \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
  Challenge 
  & \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
Challenge 
  & \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
  Challenge 
  & \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
  Challenge 
  & \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
  Challenge 
  & \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
  Challenge 
  & \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
  Challenge 
  & \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
Challenge 
  & \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
  Challenge 
  & \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
  Challenge 
  & \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
Challenge 
  & \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
  Challenge 
  & \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
  Challenge 
  & \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
Challenge 
  & \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
  Challenge 
  & \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
  Challenge 
  & \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
Challenge 
  & \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
  Challenge 
  & \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
  Challenge 
  & \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
  Challenge 
  & \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
  Challenge 
  & \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
  Challenge 
  & \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
Challenge 
  & \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
  Challenge 
  & \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
  Challenge 
  & \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
Challenge 
  & \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
  Challenge 
  & \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
  Challenge 
  & \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
Challenge 
  & \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
  Challenge 
  & \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
  Challenge 
  & \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
Challenge 
  & \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
  Challenge 
  & \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
  Challenge 
  & \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
  
\end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

Comment: note the `longtblr` environment is completely different to `longtable`

Comment: thanks for your note! @DavidCarlisle
Which environment would you recommend for my issue?

Comment: well use either, but asking about one but giving a title and tag about the other confuses people trying to help:-) I had deleted the `longtable` tag but you have put it back for some reason even though you are not using that at all.

Comment: thank you
and I'm sorry, I thought that I forget that Tag,
i just removed it again!

You are right, I forgot to add the lines for the next page.
Now it should present you that output

Comment: @OliverGatnar Why did you remove the `tabularray` tag?

Comment: that was a mistake, sorry @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz
I'm new to the community!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the package `graphicx` we have `\rotatebox{90}`

**Code**

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\newcommand\TB{\textbullet}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Tables
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption}
%
\usepackage{graphicx}%<-- for the rotate
% German Translation for "Continued on next page" and "Continued from previous page"
\DefTblrTemplate{contfoot-text}{default}{Fortsetzung auf der nächsten Seite}
\DefTblrTemplate{conthead-text}{default}{ - Fortsetzung}
\SetTblrTemplate{contfoot-text}{default}
\SetTblrTemplate{conthead-text}{default}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtblr}[
label = {tab:conceptmatrix},
caption = {Challenges - conceptmatrix},
]{
    width = \textwidth,
    colspec = {l *{11}{c}}, 
    row{1} = {font=\bfseries, bg=gray!20},
    row{2} = {font=\bfseries, c},
    row{3-Z} = {font=\normalfont},
    cell{2}{2-Z} = {cmd=\rotatebox{90}},
    hlines, vlines,
    rowhead = 1,
    rowhead = 2,
}
\SetCell[r=2]{c} Challenges 
&   \SetCell[c=11]{c}   articles
    &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &    \\
    & article1
    & article2
        & article3
                & article4
                    & article5
                        & article6
                            & article7
                                & article8
                                    & article9
                                        & article10
                                            & article11 \\
Challenge 
& \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
Challenge 
& \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
Challenge 
& \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
Challenge 
& \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
Challenge 
& \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
Challenge 
& \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
Challenge 
& \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
Challenge 
& \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
Challenge 
& \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
Challenge 
& \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
Challenge 
& \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
Challenge 
& \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
Challenge 
& \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
Challenge 
& \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
Challenge 
& \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
Challenge 
& \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
Challenge 
& \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
Challenge 
& \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
Challenge 
& \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
Challenge 
& \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
Challenge 
& \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
Challenge 
& \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
Challenge 
& \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
Challenge 
& \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
Challenge 
& \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
Challenge 
& \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
Challenge 
& \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
Challenge 
& \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
Challenge 
& \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
Challenge 
& \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
Challenge 
& \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
Challenge 
& \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
Challenge 
& \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
Challenge 
& \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
Challenge 
& \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
Challenge 
& \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
Challenge 
& \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
Challenge 
& \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
Challenge 
& \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
Challenge 
& \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
Challenge 
& \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
Challenge 
& \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
Challenge 
& \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
Challenge 
& \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
Challenge 
& \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
Challenge 
& \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
Challenge 
& \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
Challenge 
& \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
Challenge 
& \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
Challenge 
& \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
Challenge 
& \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
Challenge 
& \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
Challenge 
& \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
Challenge 
& \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
Challenge 
& \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
Challenge 
& \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
Challenge 
& \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
Challenge 
& \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
Challenge 
& \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
Challenge 
& \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
Challenge 
& \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
Challenge 
& \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
Challenge 
& \TB & & & \TB & \TB & & & & \TB & & \\
\end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much Pascal!

I just tried it in my Code and it works perfectly!
Is it possible to force the caption of the table at the bottom of it, in the longtblr environment?

Comment: @Olivier Gatnar, It seems that this is not possible (desirable?) for a `longtblr`. You should post a new question specifying whether this concerns all pages or only the last one.